# What is an explanation of the relavistic transformation of the Gaussian beam intensity?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

Linearly polarized Gaussian pulse generated in vacuum in frame $S$ propagates in the positive direction of $z$-axis in $S$. Frame $S'$ moves with velocity $v$ relative to $S$ also in the positive direction of $z$-axis.

I tried to derive how intensity of the pulse $I'$ measured in $S'$ depends on intensity $I$ measured in $S$, so I used following transformation of the electric field:

$$\textbf{E}'=(E'_x,E'_y,E'_z)=(0,E'_y,0)=(0,\gamma (E_y+vB_x),0),$$

and calculated the intensity in the $S'$ frame as follows:

\begin{align}
 I'
& =\frac{|\textbf{E}'(x,y,z)|^2}{2\eta_0}
\\ & = \frac{|E'_y|^2}{2\eta_0} = \frac{|\gamma(E_y+vBx)|^2}{2\eta_0}
\\ & =
\frac{1}{2\eta_0} \left|\left(E_0\frac{w_0}{w(z)}\mathrm{exp}\left(\frac{-x^2+y^2}{w(z)}\right)  \mathrm{exp}\left(-\mathrm{i}\left(kz+k\frac{(x^2+y^2)}{2R(z)}-\psi(z)\right)\right)\right)\gamma(1+v\frac{\mu_0}{\eta_0})\right|^2 
\\ & =
\frac{1}{2\eta_0} \left|E_0\frac{w_0}{w(z)}\mathrm{exp}\left(\frac{-x^2+y^2}{w(z)}\right)  \mathrm{exp}\left(-\mathrm{i}\left(kz+k\frac{(x^2+y^2)}{2R(z)}-\psi(z)\right)\right)\right|^2 \left|\gamma\left(1+v\frac{\mu_0}{\eta_0}\right)\right|^2 
\\ & =
I\gamma^2\left|1+v\frac{\mu_0}{\eta_0}\right|^2 
\\ & =
I\gamma^2\left(1+v\frac{\mu_0\sqrt{\varepsilon_0}}{\sqrt{mu_0}}\right)^2  \\ & =
I\gamma^2\left(1+v\sqrt{\varepsilon_0 \mu_0}\right)^2 \\ & =
I\gamma^2\left(1+\frac{v}{c}\right)^2,
\end{align}
which then gives
\begin{equation}\label{I'}
I'=I\gamma^2\left(1+\beta\right)^2=I\frac{1}{1-\beta^2}\left(1+\beta\right)^2=I\frac{1}{(1-\beta)(1+\beta)}\left(1+\beta\right)^2=I\frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}.
\end{equation}

I used the electric field and magnetic field of the Gaussian beam according to [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam).

According to my computations, it seems that when the observer in the frame $S'$ moves away from $S$, the intensity of the pulse is greater relative to the intensity in $S$. Thus, if the frame $S'$ moves towards the frame $S$, the intensity in $S'$ is lower relative to the intensity in $S$.

Is there an intuitive explanation of this transformation?

Edit:

I realized that the result depends on the polarization. If I choose $$\textbf{E}'=(E'_x,E'_y,E'_z)=(E'_x,0,0)=(\gamma (E_x-vB_y),0,0),$$ 
then
\begin{equation}
I'= I\frac{1-\beta}{1+\beta}.
\end{equation}

How is it possible?

Comment: I considered the transformation of the transverse field as $\textbf{E}'_{\perp}=\gamma(\textbf{E}_{\perp}+\bf{v}\times\textbf{B})$ and put $\textbf{v}=(0,0,v)$ and $\textbf{B}=(B_x,0,0)$. Is there any mistake in it?

Comment: I apologize, there is no mistake. I'll  delete my first comment.

Comment: ..since..\begin{equation}
\mathbf{v} \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{B}=
\begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\
0 & 0 & \upsilon \\
B_{x} & 0 & 0
\end{vmatrix}
=\left(0, \boldsymbol{+}\upsilon B_{x} ,0\right)
\tag{03}
\end{equation}

Comment: It is ok, I put $v$ in $z$ direction which is quite confusing.

Comment: However, it seems that there is really some mistake in it because if I choose $\textbf{v}=(v,0,0)$, $\textbf{E}=(0,E_y,0)$, $\textbf{B}=(0,0,B_z)$, $E'_y=E_y-vB_z$ seems right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is that I considered $E_y$ with the plus sign, although the minus sign is actually right in my configuration. Thus, $E_y=-\frac{1}{\eta}B_x$, $\textbf{E}'=(E'_x,E'_y,E'_z)=(0,E'_y,0)=(0,\gamma (-E_y+vB_x),0)$ and 
\begin{equation}
I'= I\frac{1-\beta}{1+\beta}.
\end{equation}

This means, when the observer in the frame $S′$ moves away from $S$, the intensity of the pulse actually decreases relatively to the intensity in $S$.